# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - UITableView Add Button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add names into a `UITableView`. The names will be stored as a `NSUserDefault`.

My viewDidLoad:

```
var PlayersUserDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if (PlayersUserDefault.arrayForKey("playersKey") != nil){
    players = PlayersUserDefault.arrayForKey("playersKey")
}
```

Add name button:

```
@IBAction func addButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    players!.append(namesTextBox.text)
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

When I press the `addButtonAction`, I am getting error on following:

```
players!.append(namesTextBox.text)
```

Players declaration:

```
var players = NSUserDefaults().arrayForKey("playersKey")
```

Any idea why I am getting error?
Error image:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure players are not nil there?

Answer (score 1):

In one line you use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` and in the other you create new instance of `NSUserDefaults` and ask for "playersKey". What you should do is to use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` for retrieving AND saving your players.

Take a look at the refence:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSUserDefaults_Domains

For init:

> This method does not put anything in the search list. Invoke it only
>   if you’ve allocated your own NSUserDefaults instance instead of using
>   the shared one.

and for shared instance:

> If the shared defaults object does not exist yet, it is created with a
>   search list containing the names of the following domains, in this
>   order:
>
> - NSArgumentDomain, consisting of defaults parsed from the application’s
>     arguments
> - A domain identified by the application’s bundle identifier
> - NSGlobalDomain, consisting of defaults meant to be seen by all
>     applications
> - Separate domains for each of the user’s preferred languages
> - NSRegistrationDomain, a set of temporary defaults whose values can be
>     set by the application to ensure that searches will always be
>     successful
>
> The defaults are initialized for the current user. Subsequent
>   modifications to the standard search list remain in effect even when
>   this method is invoked again—the search list is guaranteed to be
>   standard only the first time this method is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The players array is nil at the point of time thats why the array is not unwrapped. If you tap the button at the first time, your UserDefaults will not be having players, So the `players` array is nil. So you can solve this in two ways do like this.

1. On your `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
   var PlayersUserDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   if (PlayersUserDefault.arrayForKey("playersKey") != nil){
        players = PlayersUserDefault.arrayForKey("playersKey")
   }else {
        players = [String]()
   }
   ```
2. Otherwise, initialise the `players` array with an empty string array like this:

   ```
    var players = [String]()
   ```

This may help you.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that one, he should initialize as the option 2 instead of var players = NSUserDefaults().arrayForKey("playersKey")

Answer (score 0):

You could try unwrapping the value of players before attempting to do `append`. Then you will know for sure if it's `nil` or not.

Try:

```
@IBAction func addButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let playerValue = players {
        players!.append(namesTextBox.text)
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }else{
        println("players is nil!")
    }
}
```

Comment: This will save him from exception only, if he rely on the data source anywhere else it will be harder to find. Maybe its better to have exception at the source of the problem then have one error silenced only to look for it later on

Comment: After i read your answer, i realised the same thing. Your answer is better.

Comment: This worked, but somehow, it does´t add the players name into the UITableView?

Comment: It won't do anything since players are nil. You will get "players are nil!" in console if you take a look